# Pass Javascript Variable into taglib method call Grails

Tags: grails

any idea for this

```
var elemVal = $("#element").val();
var finalVal = "${someTagLib(attr: elemVal)}";
```

The element is a select option, so I am getting the value that the user selected to pass into a taglib function. It seems that search isn't being passed into the taglib. Anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible at all. You are trying to mix server side code with client side code which is a common mistake.

When you use gsp's they first compiled on server i.e. in JVM, but there javascript can not be executed. Similarly when compiled gsp content is rendered as html in the browser, there will be no `${}` since that is an groovy expression.

So the thing you are trying to achieve is not possible.

Comment: thank sir, I'm doing another way by using a remoteFunction then call tagLib in controller and pass them to gsp element

Comment: Okay. avoid using grails ajax tags like remoteFunction etc. since they are already deprecated and going to be removed in future release. So writing your own jQuery code will help in long run.